# An issue about local notification on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I am now using local notification in an application, but I find something strange.

I set up and schedule a notification like this.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil) {
    return;
}
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
now = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:dayToFinish * 24 * 60 * 60];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
int month = [components month];
int day = [components day];
int year = [components year];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setYear:year];
[dateComps setMonth:month];
[dateComps setDay:day];
[dateComps setHour:18];
[dateComps setMinute:15];
[dateComps setSecond:0];

//There are a lot to set up the fire date, you could ignore it.
NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test message %@", self.name];
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.name forKey:@"ListRecordName"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

This part of code can be invoked several times to schedule several local notifications and now the strange things come.

1. The badge number remains one although there are more than one entry in the notification center.
2. Once I click on one of the notification, all other notifications disappear. But I did not use cancelAllLocalNotifications method.

How can I fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: Well what have you tried...

Comment: localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; This code is showing the badge once (What do You Think)...

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=ysm0QKs2a3Q&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dysm0QKs2a3Q Check out this link ..

Comment: @Programmer... I don't think applicationBadgeNumber = 1 cause the problem. As the document says "The default value is 0, which means "no change.” The application should use this property’s value to increment the current icon badge number, if any." If there are more than one such notification instances. The badge number should equal to the number of notification instances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to update dynamically the badge number with local notifications while your app is in the background. You have to use push notifications.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense for the property applicationIconBadgeNumber. As the description in the document says, it should update the badge number according to this property and it does not related to the notification consumed when click on.